# Troubles with ajax. How to convert javascript variable to php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to convert javascript variable to php variable to use it in sql query,but it doesn't work.

**html code :**

```
<select id = "dep_ID" name = "dep_ID" onchange="myFunction()">
```

**javascript code in the same file:**

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){

        var xo = document.getElementById("dep_ID").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + xo;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'insert.php',                
            data: {duration: xo},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + <?php echo @$duration;?>;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**insert.php code:**

```
<?php
$duration = $_POST['xo'];
return $duration ;
?>
```

I expect the output of dep_ID variable, but i get nothing.

Comment: I think you want `$_POST['duration']`, not `$_POST['xo']`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript and PHP systax are different. In the response of ajax call you will get javascript object. So you need to do changes as follows:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + data.duration;
```

Answer (score 0):

$duration variable in PHP code is NOT defined in the HTML file that contains the javascript.

I think you're confusing what happens BEFORE the html page is produced, with what happens WHEN the page i rendered and the user selects a value, with what happens AFTER the ajax call has been done and insert.php has been executed.

To be clear, this:

gets executed BEFORE anything has happened in the browser, so $duration is undefined.